# When to apply for grad job (deferral of graduation for 1 semester)

Tags: graduate

I'm a year 4 student who will defer my graduation for 1 semester (graduate in year 5 semester 1, Dec 2019) due to an off cycle internship. Normally, year 4 students should be applying for graduate programs by now. My situation is a bit awkward that I am too late for 2019's graduate program (By the time I graduate, it is already Christmas, which is 2020-ish), but too early for 2020.

When should I apply for grad job?

Comment: @gnat: This isn't a duplicate question, he's talking about grad jobs after he enters grad school which he hasn't done yet.

Answer (score 0):

Email three Universities' grad counselling offices and explain your situation and ask what deadlines apply to you and what advice they have.

I say "three" because I've never been real impressed with counselling offices' level of competence in their own field and the rules/suggestions might differ from University to University.

Good luck.

Edit: Because of *"Normally, year 4 students should be applying for graduate programs by now."* I'm assuming he's talking about *Applying for an in college job as a grad student*